# How to use a dictionary to loop through different file names to create multiple databases in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two file location I would like to iterate through to search read the .tsv files. The first location is:

"C:\Users\User\Documents\Research\STITCH\0NN-human-STITCH\stitch.tsv"

The second is:

"C:\Users\User\Documents\Research\STITCH\1AQ-human-STITCH\stitch.tsv"

Both tsv files are the same name, but located in different folders.

Instead of using glob, I'd like to create a loop and dictionary to search through each of the files like, this:

import pandas as pd

```
file_name = 'C:/Users/User/Documents/Research/STITCH/{}-human-STITCH/stitch_interactions.tsv'
df_list = []
for i in range('ONN','1AQ'):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file_name.format(i)))
    df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

After searching through one file, I'd then like to add an element from that file to an excel sheet.

I receive an error:

```
for i in range('ONN','1AQ'):
```

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Thanks

Comment: What you have so far looks fine to me.  What is your actual question?  Does this produce an error?

Comment: I updated the post, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Range returns a sequence of numbers. This will not work with strings.
When there are only the two values, you can simply iterate over them as tuple.

```py
file_name = 'C:/Users/User/Documents/Research/STITCH/{}-human-STITCH/stitch_interactions.tsv'
df_list = []
for i in ('ONN','1AQ'):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file_name.format(i)))
    df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY `f-string` with `list comprehension`:

```
concat_df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(
    f'C:/Users/User/Documents/Research/STITCH/{i}-human-STITCH/stitch_interactions.tsv') for i in range('ONN', '1AQ')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: For the 'str' error, remove range in the for-loop.

If you want to write the whole dataframe to excel you can use df.to_excel
[pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)
You can also append using an ExcelWriter (see example when you scroll down)

If you want to write a specific row to excel you can use "iloc" if you know which row number or "loc" for row name/identifier
[pandas.DataFrame.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)
[pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc)

Scroll down for examples on how to use the functions.